# How do I reassign array positions in php?

Tags: php, arrays, array-key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to re-index the values of an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477232/how-to-re-index-the-values-of-an-array-in-php)

I'm using several php functions to carry certain data over through an array, and through the process I get arrays that print_r like the following:

```
Array ([0] => 35 [4] => 36 [6] => 34)
```

What do I have to do if I want to reorder it back to the following? (I use a for statement and need the keys to be in consecutive order starting from 0 again)

```
Array ([0] => 35 [1] => 36 [2] => 34)
```

Comment: Third time I've answered that question here this week. Search first, check the PHP manual second, THEN ask.

Comment: will do. Only if I knew the proper term for this action was 'reindexing', sigh, lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

Comment: o.O srry (-_-!) I couldn't figure out exactly how to google the answer I wanted

Comment: `foreach ($array as $value) $newarray[] = $value;` <~ Reindex the array even if you could consult no outside sources.