# How to get N element values of an array not based on the key but on array element order

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array looking like this:

```
552="text"
75="text"
120="text"
1254="text"
187="text"
...
```

I want to use array_slice() on it to get the first 3 element values and implode them but since the keys are random, array_slice() doesn't seem to work with this because i don't know the keys.

```
            $list_sliced = array_slice($list, $slice_from, $slice_to);
            $u_array[] = implode(',', $list_sliced);
```

How can i get the first 3 element values of an array with random keys?

EDIT: I actually found a solution by using this before I slice my array $new_array = array_values($old_array);

Answer (score 0):

I'f you used [`array_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to [reset the keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477232/how-to-re-index-the-values-of-an-array-in-php), you can use [`array_splice`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) as expected:

Small example:

```php
<?php

$ar = [];
$ar[75] = 'Text 75';
$ar[552] = 'Text 552';
$ar[1254] = 'Text 1254';
$ar[1756] = 'Text 1756';

$ar = array_values($ar);

$sliced = array_slice($ar, 0, 3);
var_dump($sliced);
```

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "Text 75"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "Text 552"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "Text 1254"
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLSyWxSMFWITrWGsSKNjeNBfLUQ1IrShTMTdUhgqamRghRIAcqbGhkaoIQB/FgEuamZkgSQB5QAmpRYlFRYmV8WWJOaWqxBlBIEyRTnJOZnJoClwVzQZI6CgY6CsZAJWWJRfEppbkFGlClmtb//wMA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[array_chunk()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)**

```
$output = array_chunk($input_array, 3);
var_dump($output[0]);
```